# How to extract a string with a decimal dot to a cell with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, string, format

I'm extracting some strings from email subject into sheet cells. One of them is like this:
[image]

The output in the cell is:
[image]

My decimal symbol in regional settings (Windows) is set to comma, not dot.

Code for placing the related string inside the cell:

```
sh.Range("Q" & rCount) = Mid(.Subject, 8, 5)
```

Why the difference? How to keep it "20.00" without setting cell format to text? When I input the same string manually into cell, it does not change and the cell format is still General.

Comment: `General` format eliminates `00` decimals. Try formatting  the respective column as `Number` with 2 Decimal places, before copying numbers. If you do not need **only two such decimals**, wanting the decimal number extracted from `Subject` (different than 2), you should write some code in Worksheet `Change` event, to format according to the copied string...

Comment: @FaneDuru In my data the "20.00" is meant to be a string, not a number. My decimal symbol in regional settings (Windows) is set to comma, not dot. Is Excel (VBA) just ignoring this setting? Can I force it to include it as intended?

Comment: You should state this aspect in your question. The problem comes from the fact that **for VBA the decimal separator is `.` (dot)**. In the same way as **a formula must be written using (standard) `,` (comma) separator, even if the localized list separator is `;`**.  So, you should previously format the respective column a text (`NumberFormat = "@"`). Only once...

Comment: @FaneDuru Did originally wrote this is a string for me :) Nevertheless, thank you for the explanation. This is clearly a vba formatting thing and cannot escape it other way than formatting cell content before inputting data into it.

Comment: Did you try `sh.Range("Q" & rCount) = "'" & Mid(.Subject, 8, 5)` ?

Comment: Nope. This data is processed later on and I thought such approach (ie. prefix `'` in cell value) will disrupt the next steps in my case. But sure, it still can do the job without `.NumberFormat = "@"`